# query to limit records returned by sql query based on size of data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have to create multiple excel sheets in an excel document to feed into another legacy system. This legacy system whose code can't be modified does not accept any sheet with data more than 10 MB in size.

At the moment I have a manual process that gets all the data with a sql query, which I then dump into a temporary workbook and then break that into multiple workbooks so that each workbook is not more than 10 MB. I then collate each of the sheets from those workbooks into one big workbook having multiple sheets.

I want to now simplify this multi-staged process by using a single query which can get all the records from the tables as long as the total size of all the records returned doesn't exceed 10 MB. I also want to be able to specify the next 10MB of data to be returned using the sql query. Creating a small program is not an option here. The number of columns I specify in the query can change. I want to be able to do this using a SQL query only.

Can something like this be done using SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 1):

You could use temp tables and `EXEC sp_spaceused 'tablename'` to get an estimate of how many rows you can fit into your 10MB space, then you can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` to set up your paging.

I'll be interested to hear if there is a better way to do what you're interested in.

Comment: hi. thanks for the reply. I am basically looking at a query that can include a where clause for size of data.. for eg. "select * from tablename where DATASIZE <= (1024 * 10)"  ... something like that.

Comment: I've never heard of a way to do that, I believe you're stuck picking a number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you fix the number of records for each workbook and use `row_number()`:

```
select seqnum / 100000 as WhichWorksheet, <columns you want>
from (select s.*, row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from (<your subquery here>) s
     ) s
```

(This imagines that you want 100000 rows on each Worksheet.)

You can attempt to guess the size of each row in SQL Server.  However, figuring out what you mean by 10 Mbytes is challenging -- do you mean 10 Mbytes as measured by Excel?  Do you mean 10 Mbytes in a CSV file?  Do you mean 10 Mbytes in database storage?  Or, you can ignore these questions and choose a number of rows that has worked in the past and move on to other things.

Comment: Guessing row size for each row wont work, because some columns in a row might contain lesser data than those very same columns in the next row belonging to the same recordset. some of the columns are varchar columns where there could either two words or maybe two paragraphs. At the moment I am looking at 10MB of data purely brought out from sql. I can tweak the query later so that the data fetched out amounts to 10MB in Excel. Not looking at csv at the moment. but then again thats just the same; some tweaking required so that the recordset's data will amount to 10MB in a csv.

Comment: In the past getting an approximate number of records has not helped because in a recordset where all the columns are filled to the max, I might have needed around 20 thousand records to make 10MB. In a skinny recordset from the same table with the same number of fields I have needed between 25000-30000 rows to make 10 MB. It would be nice to have a where clause for the sql query like : "select * from tablename where DATASIZE <= (1024 * 10)"

Comment: @user20358 . . . The "sp_spaceused" method might work.  I would suggest that you write a stored procedure that walks through the types and columns and adds up the values more as an estimate of the "Excel" usage rather than "database" usage.  Microsoft has lots of documentation on how much data space various types occupy.